# change delimiter (slash) size in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, formatting, delimiters

I use the division sign, together with an underscore and smash:

```
$\underline{\smash{X/P}}$
```

The result is the following:

[image]

How can I reduce the lower part of the slash, so it does not suppress the horizontal line?

Without the `$\smash$` command there is too much padding:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.
A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: Which operation or relationship does the "slash" symbol denote?

Comment: @Mico slash denote division operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a smaller version of the slash symbol. The screenshot below illustrates its look in the second "X over P" expression.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\smalldiv{\smash{\raisebox{0.29ex}{\scalebox{0.8}{/}}}}
\begin{document}
$\underline{\smash{X/P}}$
\underline{$X\smalldiv P$}
\end{document}
```

The optimal adjustment amounts will depend on the font family that's in use.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a work around using `ulem` package. Adjust `0.55ex` in

```
\setlength{\ULdepth}{0.55ex}  %% adjust this
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\setlength{\ULdepth}{0.55ex}  %% adjust this
\begin{document}
\uline{$X/P$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or if you really want to reduce the size:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}
\newcommand{\mydiv}{\raisebox{0.25ex}{\resizebox{!}{1.4ex}{/}}}
\begin{document}
\underline{$\smash[b]{X\mydiv P}$}
\end{document}
```

[image]